# a 96kb 3d first person shooter

Tags: first-person-shooter

There was a game that look like Quake-3 graphics but is only 96kb. What was its name?

In the game, there were spider-like creatures and i was shooting at them. I forgot the name.

When the executable file was run, it loaded for 5-minutes before started working.

I didnt have internet connection when i ran the executable. How come it is only 96kb but worked like a hundred-megabyte?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "procedural generation." Also, flagged as off-topic.

Comment: Finding games is off topic for this site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask here.

Answer (score 5):

That's probably [.kkrieger](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=12036) by .theprodukkt.

And yes, the answer to how is: extremely-efficient procedural generation. Wikipedia has [some more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.kkrieger) for you.